# Edit-Delete on index tables

Tags: design-patterns, tables, delete, edit

I'm redesigning an admin portal. Right not we have A LOT of index tables with Edit-Delete buttons exposed on the table.

Some of the team members want to change the pattern: remove the edit-delete from the table, move the Delete to each specific page and use the item name as a link to Edit.

I'm trying to make a very objective decision. Other than frequency of deleting, what would be good reasons to keep Edit-Delete exposed?

[image]

Comment: DaniP, did you got the anwer to your question?

Comment: yes! thanks :) it actually helped to take a decision

Answer (score 2):

**Per-line Edit Button** makes sense when

- When **all the attributes** of a row are shown,
- and Editing is happening **inline**.

Otherwise per-line edit button doesn't make sense.

Similarly, **Per-line Delete Button** (whether it is a *button* or a *cross mark*) makes sense when

- A row (record) is either **too trivial** to ask for a confirmation. For example, removing a notification from a list.
- Or the other extreme when a record is **not trivial** (other extreme) to delete and a specific information needs to be shown in the confirmation box before actually deleting the same. For example, when you delete a user you might want to show a confirmation box having specific info for that user

> This user still has pending dues worth 400 INR, would you still want
>   to delete him?

Hope this helped.